# Comparison of numbers in the form of strings

Tags: javascript, extjs

Why in JavaScript "101" > "81" is false and "101" > "100" is true .I have encountered this issue when I do sorting on my extjs grid(where my column model is string).

Comment: You need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the string for numeric comparisons.

Comment: Because alphabetically 101 comes before 81

Answer (score 2):

Thats because "101" is string, if you make a conversion can get the result correct:

```
if(Number("101") > Number("81"))
{
...
}
```

Hope help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert string to integer before comparison to get correct result.

use parseInt() function to convert string to integer.

```
if(parseInt("101") > parseInt("81"))
{

}

    OR
```

You can use number() function - converts the object argument to a number that represents the object's value.

```
if(Number("101") > Number("81"))
    {

    }
```

Difference between parseInt() & Number() - both used to convert string to integer but difference --

parseInt() parses up to the first non-digit and returns whatever it had 
parsed. 
Number() - wants to convert the entire string into a number.

Ex.

```
parseInt("123hui") - 123
Number("123hui") - NaN
```

Comment: Didn't know that, don't use it a lot. Looking at your example it looks like a very bad idea to use parseInt, because it will truncate the original value.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why i explained both. It depends on requirement but you want.

Answer (score 0):

All of your values are `string`, that's why you're doing a *string comparison*. When comparing strings, you take **letters one by one** and the first difference determines the result.

In your case "101" and "81", you take "1" and "8" in the first step. It results in "1" < "8" which becomes the final result: "101" < "81".

In the other case "101" and "100", you take "1" and "1" in the first step and "0" and "0" in the second, which both are equal. The result is determined when comparing "1" and "0" because "1" > "0", that's why "101" > "100".

If the logic of the column is numeric, the model should be specified appropriately to number.